# SWF file extraction

Tags: actionscript, flash

If I have a link to a SWF file - for example here http://redletterdaysb2b.co.uk/swf/our-video.swf
how can I extract it for use on another website?
I have downloaded the swf, but just get an error#2044 when I try and play it. does it need to go in some sort of wrapper?
thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to load a swf that in turn loads and displays a [.flv](http://redletterdaysb2b.co.uk/swf/RED_LETTER_DAYS.flv) using the FLVPlayback component. I'm guessing our-video.swf loads fine, but it probably keeps a relative reference to the .flv.

I can think of two ways to handle this:

1. Simple add a new FLVPlayback (or any other video player) on the other site but tell it to load the [.flv](http://redletterdaysb2b.co.uk/swf/RED_LETTER_DAYS.flv) file from the original site.
2. Try to copy the .flv file in the same folder as the new .swf on the new site.

With the FLVPlayback component there's another part that could cause the error: the [skin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#skin) which on the original site is [here](http://redletterdaysb2b.co.uk/swf/redletterdays.swf).

The #2024 IOError should also include an URL. 
This is your best hint to how the our-video.swf is trying to load the .swf file (using a relative(./swf/redletterdays.swf) or an absolute(/swf/redletterdays.swf) path).

Based on this, if you decide to load the player from the original site (not just the .flv file), you can work out where to place the [skin](http://redletterdaysb2b.co.uk/swf/redletterdays.swf) (i.e. in the in a folder named **swf** on the root of the new site)